# why moveToElement method is not releasing the object at drop location in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to drag and drop object using movetoelement method but I notice object is not being dropped at destination. When user moves the mouse object gets dropped.

```
''' 
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Project')]"));
Actions action=new Actions(driver);                 
action.clickAndHold(el).pause(5000).moveToElement(el, 800, -300).pause(5000).click().release().build().perform();
'''
```

Actual Result: Object gets dragged and moves to specified co-ordinates location but doesn't get released unless user moves the mouse.

Selenium: 3.141
chromedriver 76

Comment: Relevant HTML???

Comment: @Debanjan I'm sorry. I didn't get what you are trying to convey.

Comment: @sridattas He is asking for the HTML for the web page you are testing. This will help track down the problem.

Comment: @Christine Ok. HTML can't be accessed outside our network. Any other possible suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: That makes sense. I suggest changing some of the actions commands you are runnig, details in my answer below.

Comment: @Christine Thank ou for suggestions. Action does happen but object doesn't get dropped. I tried reducing pause duration and other possible actions related to dragdrop. After drop I notice a move icon but object fails to drop.

Comment: @Christine I just noticed that dnd actions mentioned below wont work on chrome browser. Works well with firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the `.click()` that appears before `.release()`.

```
action.clickAndHold(el).pause(5000).moveToElement(el, 800, -300).pause(5000).release().build().perform();
```

If that does not work, you could try shortening pause as well:

```
action.clickAndHold(el).pause(1000).moveToElement(el, 800, -300).pause(5000).release().build().perform();
```

The solution will involve playing around with various `Actions` commands until we find something just right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it could work

```
action.DragAndDropToOffset(el, 800, -300).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but only on firefox as mentioned above. Fails on chrome browser.